# How To Avoid Mixed Content with Docker Apps

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework

I am running a Django based web application inside a set of Docker containers and I'm trying to include both a REST API (using django-REST-framework) as well as the ReactJS app that consumes it.  All my other apps are served over HTTPS but I am running into `Mixed Active Content` when it comes to the React app hitting the REST API inside the Docker network.  The React App is being hosted within my NGINX container and served up as a static site.

Here's the relevant config for my Nginx container:

```
# SSL Website
server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name    *.domain.com;

    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/my_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/my_key.key;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    access_log /home/logs/error.log;
    error_log /home/logs/access.log;

    upstream django {
        server web:9000;
    }
    location /
    {
        include            uwsgi_params;

        # Proxy settings
        proxy_pass         http://django;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    # REACT APPLICATION 
    location /faqs {
        autoindex on;
        sendfile  on;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/faqs;
    }
}
```

The during development the React app was hitting my REST API from outside the network so resources calls used https like so:
`axios.get(https://myapp.domain.com/api/)`
and everything went *relatively* smoothly, barring the occasional CORS error.

However, now that both the React and the API are running inside the Docker network NGINX is not involved in the communication between containers and the routes are like so:
`axios.get(http://web:9000/api)`

This gives me the aggravating Mixed Active Content Error.

I've seen multiple questions similar to this but most are either not using Docker containers or use some NGINX directives I've already got in my config file.  Given the popularity of Docker for these kind of loosely coupled applications I would imagine solutions abound for this kind of problem.  Sadly I have not managed to come across any and as such, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done things like this many times. I'm not sure exactly what your trouble is, if you can clarify some things, it'll be easier to help: why is the react requesting over http? the fact that the react application is served from the same docker network doesn't change the fact that the client's browser (out side of the network) is calling your application.

Comment: My trouble is that I get `Mixed Content Error` on the requests to `http://web:9000/api` from my React app.  How do I convince the browser interacting with my app that all content is secure?
As  I understand it, traffic between containers should not need to be encrypted and I do not know of any means of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your application includes both an API and a web client from the same end point, you have a "gateway" in nginx that routes all requests to either end point. So far, common practice (although you are missing a load balancer, but that's a different discussion)

All requests to your API should be to https. You should also be serving your static site over https with the same certificate from the same domain. If this isn't the case - there is your problem.

Furthermore, all routes and urls inside your react application should be relative. That means that the react app doesn't need to know what your domain is. Neither should your API ideally although that is sometimes harder to do.

your axios call, given that the react app is served from the same domain over https,  should be

```
axios.get(/api)
```

Comment: Wow, I've been living in server-side apps for so long, I didn't think that the react application is entirely running on the client's browser.  That makes perfect sense!  Relative URLs fixed everything.

This app is, for now, a local network only resource.  Load balancing will likely come when we open up to outside users.